# Map values in c

Tags: c, arduino

Is there any similar map in C as there is for Arduino? I've searched but I cannot find anything similar that I can use.
Right now I got values from 50 to 700, but I want to map them so that 50 is 0 and 700 is 1023. Is there a way to do this in C?

[Map in arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Map)

```
void backRight(void)
{
        printf("Ch5 %i\n", readADC(ADC_CHANNEL_5));

        error5 = setpoint5 - (float)readADC(ADC_CHANNEL_5);
        printf("error 5 %i\n", (int) error5);

        if(abs(error5) > MIN5)
        {
            integral5 = integral5 + error5 * dt5;
        }
        derivative5 = (error5 - pre_error5)/dt5;

        output5 = Kp5 * error5 + Ki5 * integral5 + Kd5 * derivative5;

        printf("Output %i\n",(int) output5);
        if(output5 > MAX5) 
        {
            output5 = MAX5;
        }
        else if(output5 < MIN5)
        {
            output5 = MIN5;
        }

        pre_error5 = error5;
        printf("output5 %i\n", (int)output5);

        changeDutyCycle(pwm_pin8, (output5/1023)*100);
}
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with dictionaries (see my answer).

Comment: @pid: Why rejected? That question is clearly about a linear transformation function, not the datastructure "dictionary".

Comment: And a `map` function often also triggers associations with the `map()` function from functional programming.

Comment: I did not reject because it is about dictionaries but because the edit as a whole was not acceptable. To make it relevant, many other typos should have been corrected as well. Review the accepted SO policies about edits and you will see that the question text and code spacing should have been corrected, too. I very well welcome complete edits and refuse minor incomplete ones per the SO policy. I take the opportunity to point out that this is not the right place where to discuss rejections. I answer only out of politeness and you're welcome to further contribute to SO :)

Comment: @pid: Well, you actually _did_ edit, so you could very well have removed that tag, too. So why not? It _is_ definitively wrong and missleading. I don't midn my edit, Just to reject an edit because it does not cover all faults is at best unfriendly (just have no better translation at hand for what I think).

Comment: You're right, my fault. I just removed the tag. Thanks for the heads up! About the partial edits: the policy IS to reject them. This is not rudeness, there's nothing personal in this but you're free to feel the way you like.

Comment: @pid: Nothing else was my point; thank you.

Answer (score 3):

A `map` is actually a datatype like Python's `dict`, not a function.

The function from arduino would be better called `scale` or `transform`. It does two linear transformations: offset and scale. You can easily adopt that yourself by copying implementation (that is on the page you linked).

And: this is just a function; yes, you can implement and use functions in C.

Comment: I might be missing something, but why do you say that `map` is a datatype and not a function, whereas it *is* a function?

Comment: @ladislas: A map as indicated by the question and the tag actually is a datatype. Naming a cat "dog" does not make it one.

Answer (score 1):

In the link you provided, you can find the implementation of `map()`:

```
long map(long x, long in_min, long in_max, long out_min, long out_max)
{
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

It should be as easy as copy/past to implement in C...

Answer (score 0):

50-700 to 0 - 1023 won't be perfectly smooth, there will be values that won't be represented , but just take the number subtract 50 multiply by 1023 and divide by 650... Could even be a macro...

So don't use that for cryptography or anything, but scaling for a 10 bit DAC or something is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the below what you mean (supposing that you are dealing with int type):

```
int map(int value, int fromLow, int fromHigh, int toLow, int toHigh) {

int returnValue = 0;

if (value <= fromLow) return toLow;
else if (value >= fromHigh) return toHigh;
else {
    int fromDifference = fromHigh - fromLow;
    int toDifference = toHigh - toLow;

    returnValue = (value * static_cast<int>(toDifference / fromDifference)) + toLow;

return returnValue;
}
```